# How to add a line of metadata above a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is probably very simple, but I can't find an answer

I have the dataframe (where the first row are in fact colnames)

```
      a      b       c     d      e
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

And I need to include some metadata:

```
      >this is metadata
      a      b       c     d      e
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you could do if you want to retain some metadata:

1) If you want to manipulate data frames with metadata in your R session, you can create a new S3 class that inherits from `data.frame` and add a `metadata` attribute to it. You can find some relevant information [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html)

2) If you want to save a data frame with metadata to disk, you can add a comment line at the top of your csv file (or any other format that you prefer). Something like this will work:

```
con <- file(paste0(base_path, file_name),'wt')

cat(paste0(comment_string,'\n'), file = con)
write.table(your_data_frame,
              con,
              append = TRUE,
              sep = ',',
              dec = '.',
              row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE)

close(con)
```

where `comment_string` is your metadata and `your_data_frame` is your data frame.

Comment: I'm not the OP but I think this is a good answer. I was just wondering if the ``labels`` could be use in such a way since they ''describe'' the data?

Comment: @Gainz it will extract row and column numbers from a data frame.

Comment: @GabrielG. `?file`: open for writing in text mode

Comment: @GabrielG. Could you clarify your question? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: @GabrielG.I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: I think I got it: the base_path needs to exist already. If not, it will give some errors! Also, it worked when the base_path was the same as my current working directory

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use openxlsx.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Introduction.html

as in:

```
header <- "this is metadata"
df <- my dataframe

wb <- createWorkbook()
#create an empty workbook
    addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "df_name", gridLines = F) 
#add one or more worksheets specifying the name you want for the worksheet
    writeData(wb, 1, x = header, startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
#write your header to the workbook
    writeDataTable(wb, sheet = 1, df, startCol = 1, startRow = 2)#)
#write your data to the workbook
    saveWorkbook(wb, "df_name.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
#export your workbook to excel file
```

#not run for this example